# while sharing content on facebook it looks different after sharing than content shared from php

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-share

I am using `FBSDKShareDialog` to share content from my `iOS` App but it doesn't attractive like content shared with `PHP` side.

Below is my code for `FBSDKShareDialog` to share content over **facebook**.

```
let shareLinkContent:FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
shareLinkContent.contentURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
shareLinkContent.imageURL = strImageUrl
shareLinkContent.contentTitle = strName
shareLinkContent.contentDescription = "Ik heb ‘\(strName)’ beoordeeld en gaf deze whisky '\(strPercentage)' punten"

FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: shareLinkContent, delegate: self)
```

Check image below to see difference between content shared using my `iOS` App and `PHP` site.

**1. Post from iOS App.**

[image: enter image description]

**1. Post from PHP Site.**

[image]

Please tell me solution for this so I can post content to `Facebook` like `PHP` site.

I just want to share content like Second Image i.e content shared from `PHP` site.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the second one is only a link shared without image. Facebook will take the image on its own then.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images